# TypeError: render_page() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I keep getting the following error message when trying to access the personal website I'm trying to build:

```
TypeError: render_page() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I don't even know how, as I'm using render_to_response() instead of calling render_page() directly, so I assume this kind of thing would be taken care of?

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404
from django.template import Template,Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.shortcuts import *

navs = {"About Me":"/aboutme/","Teaching":"/teaching/","CV":"/cv/","Online":"/epresence/",
"Links":"/links/","Main":"/main/"}
def render_page(request,page):
    if page == "epresence":
        return epresence(request)
    elif page == "links":
        return links(request)
    elif page == "teaching":
        return teaching(request)
    else:
        return other(request,page)
def epresence(request):
    pagetitle = "My Online Presence"
    sites = {...}
    navitems = globals().get("navs")
    return render_to_response("epresence.html",locals())
def links(request):
    pagetitle = "Links"
    navitems = globals().get("navs")
    friends = {...
}
    idols = {...
}
    resources = {...}
    return render_to_response("links.html",locals())
def teaching(request):
    pagetitle = "Teaching"
    navitems = globals().get("navs")
    teach = [...]
    learn = [...]
    return render_to_response("teaching.html",locals())
def other(request,page):
    pages = {"about":"About Me","me":"About Me","cv":"CV","home":"Home","main":"Home",}
    patetitle = pages.get(page)
    navitems = globals().get("navs")
    return render_to_response("main.html",locals())
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from personalsite.views import *
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^.*$',render_page),
)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've no idea what "I'm using render_to_response() instead of calling render_page() directly" means. You're calling `render_page` from your urlconf - however, you're not passing it any of the URL, because you're not using a group in the regex.

You should be capturing the parameter like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<page>.*)$',render_page),
```

(Note however this is a fairly strange thing to want to do. The whole point of the URLconf is to match against specific URLs and dispatch to specific view functions: so that you match `epresence` in the urlconf and get it to call the epresence function directly. Also, you should look into [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) to pass your `navs` dict to every template.)

Comment: I would also like to add that the URL dispatcher is EXTREMELY fast due to it compiling the regex. Doing it the @swizzard way is most definitely a hit on performance.